# How can i make a rails model invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a product model from an unique product. So when a user bought this model nobody can buy it again and the seller can not the same person then the buyer.

When I will buy the product I call the method product.buy(buyer). But this method should make the model invalid when the buyer = seller and date.sale != nil. But this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
   def buy(buyer)
    if self.user != buyer

      if self.date_sale.nil? 
        self.date_sale = Time.now
        self.buyer = buyer
      else
        # self.errors.add(:buyer, "article bougth") # Dont't work
      end             
    else
       # self.errors.add(:buyer, "seller can not buyer") # Dont't work
    end  
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

To handle nil date_sale, add this on top of your model:

```
validate_presence_of :date_sale
```

To check if buyer != seller you could do

```
validate :buyer_is_not_seller

def buyer_is_not_seller
  errors.add(:buyer, "shouldn't be seller") if buyer.id == seller.id
end
```

Comment: minor typo: validate :buyer_is_not_seller

Comment: Hello,thank you but i need this validation only when a user execute the buy method. I check with _date_sale that the article is sold. When i check every time that date_sale != nil, means this that every article is sold.

Answer (score 0):

Validation content might work:

```
class Domain
  validates_presence_of :name, on: :renew
end

domain = Domain.new
domain.valid?(:renew) # false
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F