# rails custom validation on action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, state-machine

I would like to know if there's a way to use rails validations on a custom action.

For example I would like do something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :description, :on => :publish, :message => "can't be blank"
```

I do basic validations create and save, but there are a great many things I don't want to require up front.  Ie, they should be able to save a barebones record without validating all the fields, however I have a custom "publish" action and state in my controller and model that when used should validate to make sure the record is 100%

The above example didn't work, any ideas?

UPDATE:

My state machine looks like this:

```
  include ActiveRecord::Transitions
  state_machine do 
    state :draft
    state :active
    state :offline

    event :publish do
      transitions :to => :active, :from => :draft, :on_transition => :do_submit_to_user, :guard => :validates_a_lot?
    end

  end
```

I found that I can add guards, but still I'd like to be able to use rails validations instead of doing it all on a custom method.

Comment: Validation context might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920829/how-can-i-make-a-rails-model-invalid/49842615#49842615

Answer (score 5):

That looks more like business logic rather than model validation to me. I was in a project a few years ago in which we had to publish articles, and lots of the business rules were enforced just at that moment.

I would suggest you to do something like Model.publish() and that method should enforce all the business rules in order for the item to be published.

One option is to run a custom validation method, but you might need to add some fields to your model. Here's an example - I'll assume that you Model is called article

```
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :ready_to_publish

  def publish
    self.published = true
    //and anything else you need to do in order to mark an article as published
  end

  private
  def ready_to_publish
    if( published? ) 
      //checks that all fields are set 
      errors.add(:description, "enter a description") if self.description.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

In this example, the client code should call `an_article.publish` and when `article.save` is invoked it will do the rest automatically. The other **big** benefit of this approach is that your model will always be consistent, rather than depending on which action was invoked.

Comment: A variation on this worked for me, however, how would I display the errors in my show view?

Answer (score 1):

If your 'publish' action sets some kind of status field to 'published' then you could do:

```
validates_presence_of :description, :if => Proc.new { |a| a.state == 'published' }
```

or, if each state has its own method

```
validates_presence_of :description, :if => Proc.new { |a| a.published? }
```

Comment: the second one looked promising, but didn't work. ;-(  i updated my question.